# Plural of that and there

Tags: plural-forms

I am writing a humor essay that begins:

> "Put that over there," she says.

Would "a room full of thats and theres" work in this context?

> Since I am standing in **a room full of both thats and theres**, I am unsure what she means.

In this humorous context, what is the plural of that and there?

Comment: Do you mean for the second section? "Room full of thats and theres"? It might help to make the part you're specifically discussing bold.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  Would "a room full of thats and theres" work in this context?

Comment: Ah, so the second sentence is what you're hoping to write? I think striped yak has done a good job of addressing that. :)

Answer (score 2):

"Thats and theres" would work. That's not the way those words are customarily used but in a humorous context it works.

I could also see:

> "that"s and "there"s

but that's very awkward; I like your choice better.

Comment: I think in the context of humor, both options are good. The quotes may even enhance it a bit.

Comment: Agreed @catija! It would be a different tone but would work equally well in humor I think.